# How do I find if an array contains pre-specified pairs?

Tags: c, arrays, path, network-programming

I am storing a set of paths in a graph/network in the form of 2D array. Each row represents a separate path and each element in the row represents nodes that have to be visited in order.

I want to find out if certain pairs of nodes lie on that path.

**Example:**

```
path1 = 4 5 6 1
path2 = 4 6 8 5 1
```

I want to search if the pair (6,5) lies in a path. path1 does not satisfy the criteria since it has 5 before 6 but path2 qualifies because it has 5 after 6.

Comment: Right now I am searching for the first element of the pair starting from the first element till the (n-1)th element and the second element of the pair from the second element of each row till the last element using for loops, but I am looking for something better.

Comment: Show the code you have written and explain where you are having difficulties.

Comment: No need to start looking for Y at location prior to where you found X.

Comment: if consecutive paths that you have have no relation among them, you will have to traverse the whole array to find ordered (X,Y) occurance for all paths. Find 'X', if it occurs, then find 'Y'. If path has no repetitions, then if you find 'Y' before 'X', break. Small optimizations such as these can be made but complexity will be O(n) for each path.

Comment: This is not network-programming